# making a weighted random state function extensible

Tags: python, function, random

I have a weighted random state function which takes a finite numbers of relative weightings and outputs an integer based on a pseudo-random choice. However, I want to make the function extensible to handle n number of states/weightings. What is an elegant way to rewrite this function where it can take *args as input?

EDIT: Since these weightings are relative to one another, the tricky part for me is thinking of the best way to make the elif logic extensible.

```
def weighted_random(weight1, weight2, weight3, weight4, weight5, weight6, weight7, weight8):
    totalWeight = weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5 + weight6 + weight7 + weight8
    randomInt = random.randint(1, totalWeight)

    if randomInt <= weight1:
        return 0
    elif randomInt > weight1 and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2):
        return 1
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2) and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2 + weight3):
        return 2
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2 + weight3) and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4):
        return 3
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4) and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5):
        return 4
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5) and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5 + weight6):
        return 5
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5 + weight6) and randomInt <= (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5 + weight6 + weight7):
        return 6
    elif randomInt > (weight1 + weight2 + weight3 + weight4 + weight5 + weight6 + weight7):
        return 7
    else:
        return("error")
```

Comment: Are your weights assumed to be sorted integers?

Comment: @dawg I think they are integers, but not sorted. Something like `weighted_random(5, 1, 4)` would give you 50% to hit index 0, 10% for index 1 and 40% for index 2.

Comment: @fafl: The the way it is being calculated, mathematically, does not support that.

Comment: @dawg Hmmm looks fine to me. Do you have an example where it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*args` to get all arguments as a list. Then you can iterate through them to find which one `randomInt` has hit.

```
def weighted_random(*weights):
    totalWeight = sum(weights)
    randomInt = random.randint(1, totalWeight)

    for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
        if randomInt <= weight:
            return i
        randomInt -= weight

    return "error"
```

If this is too readable or O(n) is too fast then try this one:

```
def weighted_random(*weights):
    randomInt = random.randint(1, sum(weights))
    return next((
        i for i in range(len)
        if sum(weights[:i+1]) < randomInt <= sum(weights[:i+2])
    ), "error")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the tricky part is making the logic of the elif statements extensible. Since the weightings here have to be relative, I first sum all the weightings and then allow the random integer to fall through the conditional statement which matches specified devision the whole. I understand how one would do this pythonicly with a for-loop. What I don't get is a really beautiful one-liner to do that logic.

Comment: @DanielMiller I don't get why you want this but I added something shorter

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. I can see how your first version might favored for its readability as you point out. Always nice to know several ways to do something though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a function that uses cumulative weights, you can do something along these lines (assuming Python 3.6+):

```
import random 
import itertools as it

def wran(*weights):
    li=random.choices(list(range(len(weights))),cum_weights=list(it.accumulate(weights)))
    return li[0]
```

So suppose you want `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` with the weighting of `[50,5,5,5,15,20]` (which, since they add up to 100 can be seen as percentages) you can do:

```
from collections import Counter
>>> t=100000 
>>> [(k,'{:.6}%'.format(float(v)/t*100)) for k,v in sorted(Counter(wran(50,5,5,5,15,20) for _ in range(t)).items())]
[(0, '49.926%'), (1, '4.922%'), (2, '5.015%'), (3, '5.067%'), (4, '15.125%'), (5, '19.945%')]
```

Which is close to the percentages assumed.

---

If you want to do this on a Python other than Python 3.6+, you can generate tuples of the cumulated sums of the list and then use `bisect` to get the index of where a random number would fit in that list of tuples:

```
import bisect
def wran(*weights):
    totalWeight = sum(weights)
    randomInt = random.randint(1, totalWeight)
    li=[(sum(weights[0:i]),sum(weights[0:i+1])) for i in range(len(weights))]
    return bisect.bisect_left(li,(randomInt,))-1
```

Testing this:

```
>>> [(k,'{:.6}%'.format(float(v)/t*100)) for k,v in sorted(Counter(wran(50,5,5,5,20,5,5,5) for _ in range(t)).items())]
[(0, '49.943%'), (1, '4.979%'), (2, '5.048%'), (3, '4.968%'), (4, '20.06%'), (5, '5.059%'), (6, '4.954%'), (7, '4.989%')]
```

Compared to the function originally posted:

```
>>> [(k,'{:.6}%'.format(float(v)/t*100)) for k,v in sorted(Counter(weighted_random(50,5,5,5,20,5,5,5) for _ in range(t)).items())]
[(0, '49.986%'), (1, '5.203%'), (2, '4.962%'), (3, '4.998%'), (4, '19.977%'), (5, '5.004%'), (6, '4.986%'), (7, '4.884%')]
```